# Finding a primitive root modulo for integer $n=4$

Tags: number-theory

Find a primitive root modulo for integer $n=4$. How many incongruent primitive roots do we have?

I know without a doubt that to find how many incongruent primitive roots there are, you find $\phi(\phi(n))$. But I am struggling to find the primitive root modulo.

Please can someone explain the answer to this question

Comment: For the case of $n=4$, $\varphi(\varphi(4))=\varphi(2)=1$

Comment: Yes, I know that but what does that have to do with finding a primitive root modulo for integer $n=4$?

Comment: Your question asks about the number of primitive roots you have. I don't know if you want a proof of why the number of distinct primitive roots is $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ or the number of primitive roots for modulo $n=4$.

Comment: Well from the book that I am reading, the answer is 3. I think it is asking for the least positive primitive roots modulo 4

Comment: the only primitive root mod 4 is 3. it is (an equivalence class of) numbers relatively prime to $4,$ such that every number relatively prime to $4$ is a power of the root. The chocies are $1,3.$ $1$ does not work.